# return infinite loop python success

Tags: python, loops

I am learning Python online but do not understand the last step i should take.

**here is the question**

Write a function execute(prog) to do the following. Assume prog is a list of strings containing the BASIC program, like before. Then, your function should return either `"success" or "infinite loop"` depending on whether the program terminates, or loops forever. Important: you should assume the procedure `findLine(prog, target)` defined in sub-task 2 is already defined, you do not need to re-write it. Hint

Input example:`(['5 GOTO 30', '10 GOTO 20', '20 GOTO 10', '30 GOTO 40', '40 END'])`

My code still returns `"infinite loop"` when it should return success but I really cannot find the last required step. ( I include all my debugging checks here also)

```
def execute(prog):
  location = 0
       #print('prog = ', prog)
  visited = [False] * len(prog)

  while True:
     for i in range (0,len(prog)):
        visited[i] = True  
      #print('prog is type=',type(prog))
      # print(type(location))
      #print('len of prog=', len(prog))
      #for i in range (0,len(prog)):
       #  visited[i] = True  
      #   print('visited =', visited)
       #  print('visited[i] =', visited[i])
        # print('prog[i] =', prog[i])     
  findT = prog[location].split()
      #print('findT = ',findT)
  T = findT[-1]
      #print('T=',T)
  location = findLine(prog, T)
      #print('new location=', location)
  if visited[location]:
     return "infinite loop"
  elif location==len(prog)-1: 
     return "success"
         #print('T=',T)
      #print('prog = ', prog)
```

***hint: here is my getBASIC() and findline() code that I wrote and works:***

```
def getBASIC():
   myList = []
   while True:
      line = str(input())
      myList.append(line)
      if line.endswith("END"):
        break
   return myList


def findLine(prog, target):
   for i in range(0, len(prog)):  #range doesn't include last element.
     progX = prog[i].split()
     if progX[0] == target:
          return i
```

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation of your program?

Comment: You forced the whole "visited" list to True, after having initialized it to False, so the final check "if visited[location]" is always  valid. You also forgot to set visited[location] when actually visited...

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to get a solution for the stop problem. I'm afraid that there is no solution to the stop problem (and that has been prooved).

Comment: @skyking He could definitely get it working for trivial programs like the example input. (If you're talking about [Halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)) The problem is to get it work for **any** program.

Comment: @loesbrown `findLine(prog, target) ` this function is needed. May be you do it before.

Comment: def findLine(prog, target):
   for i in range(0, len(prog)):  #range doesn't include last element.
     progX = prog[i].split()
     if progX[0] == target:
          return i